# communicate between servlet and angular 4

Tags: java, json, angular, servlets

i'm working on create a java web app using servlet in controller side and the angular in front-end.. this app uses javamail api to get emails from an email account (like gmail) then return them as a json format .. i did all of that .. i can bring the emails messages and i return them in json format using servlet but my problem here is that i can't display them using angular.. i tried to test my code with this website "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users" to test my angular with json and it bring all data but when i modify it and try it with my app it doesn't bring any thing..
here is an example of json data from my app..
[image]

and that's the servlet code who print this data:

```
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
        EmailAccount emailaccount= new EmailAccount("myemail@gmail.com","HardPas$$word!@");
        EmailServices read = new EmailServices();
        ArrayList<Email> emails = new ArrayList<Email>();
        emails = read.readEmail(emailaccount);      

        String json = new Gson().toJson(emails.get(2));
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(json);
        }
```

and this this the codes in angular to get the json data and display it:

html

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:8080/oneBox/ReadEmail" method="POST" (submit)="onSubmit()">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
        <ul >
            <li>
                {{users.id}}
            </li>
            <li>
                {{users.title}}  ---- {{users.from}}
            </li>
            <li>
                {{users.to}}
            </li>
        </ul>
```

component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MyServiceService } from '../../services/my-service.service';
import {EmailModel} from '../../models/user.model'




@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-compo',
  templateUrl: './my-compo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-compo.component.css']
})
export class MyCompoComponent implements OnInit {

users:EmailModel;

  constructor(public service:MyServiceService) {



   }

   onSubmit(){
    this.service.getUsers().subscribe(

      users => {this.users=users;});
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

and my service code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

import {map, catchError} from "rxjs/operators";

import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyServiceService {


url="http://127.0.0.1:8080/oneBox/ReadEmail";

getUsers():Observable<any>{

    return this.http.get(this.url)
           .pipe(map(res => res.json()));

            }

  constructor(public http: Http) { }
}
```

so my question here is **how can i bring these json data from my local server and print it using angular** ?

Answer (score 1):

Your backend seems to be working fine, as you get a proper JSON response from the Java side of things.

Try the following in your service class:

```
getUsers(): Observable<any>{
   return this.http.get<any>(this.url); 
}
```

Add the error callback inside your component controller and log the result of both fields, provide us with the result afterwards in the comments:

```
onSubmit(){
  this.service.getUsers().subscribe(
    users => {
        console.log(users);
        this.users=users;
    }, 
    error => {
       console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Further more, I think that there is a misconception between POST and GET requests, as I saw this in your form. Remove the `method` and `action` attribute in your form, since in Angular this will have no effects. You submit your forms with the `(submit)` event, so that is enough.

Last but not least, have you considered CORS policy in your backend? This is an issue with frontend/backend separation, since the backend will only allow request coming from the same IP and Port, thus not your Angular frontend. Probably this could help you: https://howtodoinjava.com/servlets/java-cors-filter-example/

Comment: thanks,i tried your suggestions but it still doesn't work .. some peoples recommended me to learn spring to avoid this problems and i guess this is the best solution ..

Comment: @hegeey Of course, Spring is the much better option. Spring (and all the other higher level Java web frameworks) are based on the Servlet API and extend its functionality to be easier to use. However, to learn how those higher level frameworks work under the hood, learning the Servlet API is a good approach from you. That was the reason why I upvoted your question btw, because one can see you are trying to understand the backgrounds of Java development. If your question is still active, response to my comment with some updated code and I will have a much deeper look on it.